# What is the [pottermore] tag used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Five questions have the [pottermore](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pottermore) tag. I presume that @ibid knows what the tag is for, since he wrote four out of the five questions. Two questions are about [Pottermore](http://pottermore.com/) specifically, but I don't know why the other three have it as a tag.

My suggestion: either write a tag wiki excerpt or remove the tag, presumably with ibid's input.

Comment: Much like many tags on the site, it is applied to questions where a word is mentioned in the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having "Pottermore" as a tag only makes sense when the question is *about* Pottermore. As you mention, this applies to two of the (currently) five [pottermore](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pottermore)-tagged questions:

- [Why was the old Pottermore shut down?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115453/why-was-the-old-pottermore-shut-down)
- [What are the differences between old Pottermore and new?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113605/what-are-the-differences-between-old-pottermore-and-new)

My best guess is that, for two of the remaining three, it was used because the question was motivated by information gathered from Pottermore:

- [Why would the Headmaster try re-curing Dragon Pox?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115239/why-would-the-headmaster-try-re-curing-dragon-pox) is motivated by one the Pottermore sorting quiz
- [What happened to each of The Original Forty?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112014/what-happened-to-each-of-the-original-forty) is motivated by a piece of original writing posted on Pottermore

This is not, to my mind, a good reason for a tag. It's worth pointing out that one of the suggested edit [rejection reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected/239950#239950) is:

> **Irrelevant tags**
>
> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*.

No sensible interpretation would argue that those two questions are *about* Pottermore; they're about the *Harry Potter* canon, and we already have a tag for that.

The final question, [Why isn't Draco Malfoy behind bars in Azkaban?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123493/why-isnt-draco-malfoy-behind-bars-in-azkaban), I assume had the tag added as a way to motivate answers - perhaps to indicate that Pottermore is an acceptable source. Again, the question isn't *about* Pottermore.

If we're *going* to keep it<sup>1</sup>, that's the only sensible usage guidance: for questions about the Pottermore *website*.

---

<sup>1</sup> And, personally, I don't have strong feelings either way; it's clearly not a tag that's getting used a whole lot, but it also doesn't really hurt anyone to have, so long as its use is policed

Comment: "had the tag added as a way to motivate answers - perhaps to indicate that Pottermore is an acceptable source" - isn't this also how the SW Legends tag is used?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm under the impression that Pottermore is only a website, without its own level of canon, rather than forming a Harry Potter extended universe, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @amarillo Pottermore includes a lot of material actually written by JKR, and forms its own level of canon. In fact, according to [the accepted answer to the question about HP canon levels](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117948/which-harry-potter-works-are-considered-canon), it's the *highest* level of canon. (Not sure I'd agree with that, but under any interpretation it's pretty damn high on the canon ladder.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor If its level of canon is that high, wouldn't Pottermore canon be acceptable as an answer to any Harry Potter question? For [tag:star-wars-legends] and [tag:star-trek-eu], they're non-canon, so people need to explicitly allow answers from those sources.

Comment: @amarillo I suppose so, but not many people know Pottermore exists (I didn't until I'd spent a while on this site). Casual fans are looking for answers from the books or even the films. FWIW, I agree with Jason's answer - just wanted to note that there's precedent for having a tag to indicate what canon levels the OP wants.

Comment: The other two questions were tagged such because they were solely asking about the canonicity of Pottermore content. This was before I found out that [we don't have tags for different Harry Potter works](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8132/why-dont-we-have-tags-for-each-harry-potter-installment).

Comment: I have a different Pottermore question I've been meaning to ask for a while, but it's another self-answer.

Comment: @ibid What do you think the tag wiki excerpt should be for the tag? Are there any questions with the tag that shouldn't have it?

Comment: @amarillo - 1)Questions about the site - yes. 2)Questions about content found on the site - maybe (Based on our policy for individual Harry Potter books, I would say no, but I can see why this might be different. Also, hard to draw the line between this and #1. 3)To indicate that Pottermore is an accepted source - No (standard SFF policy already allows Pottermore answers on HP questions.)

Comment: @ibid Maybe you or I could write a tag wiki excerpt mentioning the first two points, leave your four questions alone, and then remove the tag from the other person's question. Unless you think it would be better to untag any of your questions. I just want to make sure that whatever is tagged [tag:pottermore] fits the description in the wiki excerpt.

Comment: @amarillo - I removed the tag from two questions, bringing the total down to three.

Comment: @ibid Kevin decided to remove the tag from another question. The two questions that still have the tag are about the website itself. I wrote a tag wiki excerpt--feel free to edit it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor -- Whoa. Not a lot of people know about Pottermore? We hardcore Potter geeks *totally* know about Pottermore; many of us consider it an important extension of canon. Because you didn't know about it certainly doesn't mean Pottermore isn't a popular site for Potter fans. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Of course all hardcore Potter geeks know about Pottermore! Just not most of the rest of us :-)