# How should we tag Harry Potter questions about original media based on details from new media?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question is an example:

[Why was Hogwarts so adamant about having Harry go there?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152792/why-was-hogwarts-so-adamant-about-having-harry-go-there)

It's specifically about an original character, Harry, in an original situation (we're talking book 1).

However, the question is based on or inspired by a concept introduced in the new *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* movie.

Currently, it has both [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) and [fantastic-beasts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts). The question isn't specifically *about* the *Fantastic Beasts* franchise, though.

Another scenario would be reading something on Pottermore, and asking a question about *Goblet of Fire* based on that reading, not about the Pottermore content itself, but tagging it Pottermore anyway.

There's stuff from the new media in the question, and the answer may reasonably draw upon the new media, but it's technically asking about events in old media or just the "franchise" in general.

So, what should our tagging standards be?

Comment: Similar discussion: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9420/31051

Comment: @JasonBaker Indeed! I'm worried Fantastic Beasts is going to grow into quite a beast with the planned films, though, compared to Pottermore, and we have an opportunity to avoid the pitfalls of the `harry-potter` tag.

Comment: should there be a tag for 'wizarding-world-of-jk-rowling' (ok - maybe something a little less tedious) instead? In this particular case the question is about HP specifically but it could be that eventually there would be a question that isn't specific to either property explicitly but the universe as a whole - maybe too navel gazey - futureific at this point

Comment: @NKCampbell Well, that's what `harry-potter` *was*, but that universe unexpectedly exploded and our tags didn't catch up. So, `harry-potter` is still generic for the entire franchise.

Answer (score 8):

### [Kill it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRBC1.png)

I've [previous argued](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9420/31051) (in an discussion about [pottermore](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pottermore)) that "source" tags only make sense when the question is *about* that source. That's most consistent with the general purpose of tags:

- **Scope clarification**. The scope of a question isn't clarified by knowing what inspired it
- **Ease of searching**. I don't have hard evidence to back this supposition up, but I suspect few people would ever want to find questions that were inspired by a particular source (except for when the question is also *about* that source)
- **Categorization**. In the same vein as the other two: there's negligible benefit to indexing questions by their inspirations; I suspect it's something few people would ever need to know

All of this is to say: no, remove [fantastic-beasts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts) from this question; we only have five tags on a question, so let's keep them to things the question is actually *about*.

Comment: In fact, I saved everyone the hassle and removed the tag myself

Comment: Just to be clear, this was just a recent example, and I expect this to come up more. This is your _general_ stance?

Comment: @CreationEdge Yes, this is my general stance. To quote the great philosophers, tags should help to describe what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*.

Comment: I really don't disagree! "Kill it" seems to be a narrow wording to the specific example, though. Additionally, is there any argument to be made that the question *is* also about the other tag (I don't think so, but is there anyone with an opposing view?)

Comment: @CreationEdge There may be an opposing argument; I can't imagine a terribly sensible one, but I'm welcome to being proven wrong

Comment: I think this is another, then? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119886/students-expelled-from-hogwarts-breaking-of-wands-and-complete-education

Comment: I believe you actually wanted to say _burninate it_, not kill it.

Comment: I believe the typical counterargument is that tags are/can be/should be viewed as a "bat-signal" for experts. In this case, as I understand it, a FB tag might be useful as a FB expert might be alerted and come in to answer the question.

Comment: Granted, I'd expect that any one following a FB tag, would *likely* already be following the HP tag.